# ¿En PHP es posible recuperar en otro array los valores eliminados con unset?

Tags: php

Estuve probando la función de [Jack P.](http://rextester.com/ZPDS13319), en la cual, dado un `$arrOriginal`  y un `$arrRemover`  es posible obtener un `$arrNuevo` sin las claves indicadas `$arrRemover`.

Pero, ¿si quisiera también recuperar en un `$arrRemovidos` los valores y claves eliminados con `unset`, cómo podría hacerlo? Es decir, tener dos arrays, uno con las claves y valores que no se encuentran en `$arrRemover` y otro con las claves y valores que sí se encuentran en `$arrRemover`.

Estuve mirando si `unset` tenía algún contrario, pero no encontré nada.

Expresado en código sería:

```
$arrOriginal=
        array(
                array(
                        "Id"=> 1,
                        "Nombre"=> "Pedro",
                        "Ciudad"=> "Galilea"
                      ),

                array(
                        "Id"=> 2,
                        "Nombre"=> "Santiago",
                        "Ciudad"=> "Betsaida"
                     )
            );
```

---

```
$arrRemover=array("Id","Nombre");
```

---

Esto es lo que hace la función:

```
$arrNuevo=
        array(
                array(
                        "Ciudad"=> "Galilea"
                      ),

                array(
                        "Ciudad"=> "Betsaida"
                     )
            );
```

---

Esto es lo que quisiera también obtener, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

```
$arrRemovidos=
        array(
                array(
                        "Id"=> 1,
                        "Nombre"=> "Pedro"
                      ),

                array(
                        "Id"=> 2,
                        "Nombre"=> "Santiago"
                     )
            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo tengo, esta es una versión modificada de la función original.

Agregué la variable `$removed` para ir conservando los valores a medida que se eliminan.

En la variable `$old` se copia el contenido de `$array` antes de empezar a quitarle elementos, y luego al final se compara con el contenido que haya quedado.

La función `array_diff_key` te devuelve un array con todas las claves que están en `$old` y no están en `$array`.

```
function array_remove_keys($array, $keys, &$removed)
{      
  $old = $array;

  // Loop over the array
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    // Check if we want to remove it...

    if (!is_numeric($key) and in_array($key, $keys)) {      
        unset($array[$key]);
        continue;
   }        

    // Filter the value if it's an array also
    $array[$key] = is_array($value) ? array_remove_keys($value, $keys, $removed) : $value;

   }

   $diff = array_diff_key($old, $array);
   if (count($diff) > 0) {
     $removed[] = $diff;
   }    

   return $array;
}
```

Luego, con el ejemplo:

```
$arrOriginal=
            array(
            array(
                    "Id"=> 1,
                    "Nombre"=> "Pedro",
                    "Ciudad"=> "Galilea"
                  ),

            array(
                    "Id"=> 2,
                    "Nombre"=> "Santiago",
                    "Ciudad"=> "Betsaida"
                 )
        );

$arrRemover=array("Id","Nombre");

$arrRemovidos = array();
$arrNuevo = array_remove_keys($arrOriginal, $arrRemover, $arrRemovidos);

var_dump($arrRemovidos);
```

Resultado:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Id' => int 1
      'Nombre' => string 'Pedro' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'Id' => int 2
      'Nombre' => string 'Santiago' (length=8)
```